# Remove logo from homepage - Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, css-selectors

I want to remove the logo from the home page: http://www.evolutionhairandextensions.co.uk

I have tried removing the logo from Appearance > Customise as well as adding this in to the css:

```
.home .logo {display: none!important; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ther is no element `.home .logo` in your markup, but a class `.header-logo`.

If you can't edit the markup (which would be preferable), you can just hide the whole logo wrapper div, e.g. with adding the following to your style.css:

```
.home .header-logo {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: The `.home` class is added to body by WordPress. so the correct answer would be `.home .header-logo { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

Add this code into your style.css file

```
.header-logo{
  display:none;
}
```

OR

```
.header-logo img{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add style logo instead of header-logo

```
.header-logo{display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.header-logo img{visibility: hidden;}
```

Or

```
.header-logo img{display: none;}
```

you can try anyone

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with CSS.
I did that with this code:

```
.home .menu-item-logo {
    display: none !important; 
}
```